# Oracle 10g column width (byte size) for UTF-8 character set / encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, oracle10g

I'm still a bit of a stranger when it comes to character set and encoding, so I apologize in advance for any of my misconception.

I'm using Oracle 10g as a DBMS for my web application. My database is configured to UTF-8.

Database information:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                   $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET               UTF8
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              AMERICAN
NLS_SORT                       BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              $
NLS_COMP                       BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         UTF8
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION              10.2.0.3.0
```

I have a database table that contains a column with a width limit of **1500**.

Table details:

```
COLUMN_NAME                    DATATYPE
------------------------------ --------------------------------
TEST_COLUMN                    VARCHAR2(1500 BYTE)
```

Initially, being the noobie I am, I thought that the **1500** limit, which was set to the column, was a unit of number of **CHARACTER**, but found out later that it actually is the unit of number of **BYTE**.

What I am aiming at is to limit the number of character's to **1500**, thus setting `VARCHAR2(1500)` would only apply to single-byte encoding.

So because I am using UTF-8, which uses multi-byte encoding, I was wondering what would be the correct value to set on my column width which would limit it to **1500** multi-byte character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the column you need to specify character length semantics, like this:

```
test_column varchar2(1500 char)
```

You can set a default through [NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams150.htm#CHDFHDJI).  It's possible that your scripts may have worked correctly in a different environment because of the server or session parameters.  But it is probably better to explicitly set each column.

Comment: Thanks jonearles! I didn't know you can define the semantics to characters. Thank you so much!